# Linq to SQL, insert row with foreign keys

Tags: linq-to-sql, foreign-keys

I found this URL about how to add an item in my table.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386941.aspx

```
// Create a new Order object.
Order ord = new Order
{
    OrderID = 12000,
    ShipCity = "Seattle",
    OrderDate = DateTime.Now
    // …
};
```

This should work without any problems

but if I have something like this:

```
// Create a new Order object.
Order ord = new Order
{
    OrderID = 12000,
    CustomerID = 22, // where CustomerID is a foreign key to table Customer
    ShipCity = "Seattle",
    OrderDate = DateTime.Now
    // …
};
```

Then it will give errors like: 
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK7_REVIEW". The conflict occurred in database "Dbname", table "dbo.Customer", column 'CustomerID'.
The statement has been terminated.

How can I insert a row in my table, whith foreign keys?

Comment: it would mean a great deal if you also checked to see the data in the `Customer` table. Does it have a customer with an `ID`=22? The error text refers to this exact issue. Also, is the database schema correct? Verify it once more. Is this foreign key correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Order.CustomerID` refers to a primary key in another table (say `Customer`). To insert the new order, the `CustomerID` must be equal to an existing value of the primary key in `Customer` table.

Comment: Thanks, that works for me. I was thinking a way to difficult. And testing for a non existing customer.